# NameError (undefined local variable or method `current_user') in ActiveJob

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activejob

I am creating a job for the first time in Rails to send an email to the `current_user` when they create a form.

**Create method**

```
def create
    @pdform = Pdform.new(pdform_params)

    if user_signed_in?
      @pdform.user_id = current_user.id
    end

    respond_to do |format|
      if @pdform.save
        SubmissionJob.perform_later(current_user, @pdform)
        format.html { redirect_to new_pdform_requisition_path(@pdform) }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
      end
    end
  end
```

I am passing the `current_user` and the `@pdform` in the job arguments.

**Submission job**

```
class SubmissionJob < ApplicationJob
  queue_as :default

  def perform(*args)
    @user = current_user

    NewPdform.notify_user(@user, @pdform).deliver
  end
end
```

If I am passing the `current_user` object in the parameters in the arguments andassigning it to the `@user` variable how is there no defined method for current_user?

I have this check to set the user_id of the `pdform` to the `current_user` id and that is being populated when I create the form which means there is a user. So why would this result in a `NameError`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `current_user` object is only available by default in controllers and views.
You need to pass it to your job as an argument:

Replace:

```
def perform(*args)
```

By:

```
def perform(current_user, pdform)
```

or even :

```
def perform(user, pdform)
  NewPdform.notify_user(user, pdform).deliver
end
```